# Get gmail account with yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have implemented the extension EAuth Yii2 for authentication by Gmail.
Until now and it was all good except that I can not get the user's mail, this method picks me user name, id, google plus account but do not bring me the mail account.And look in google and can not find solution, someone I succor please.
Yii::$app->user->identity

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself, because I found the solution and put it in case someone else's worth it:

1. Edit file GoogleOAuth2Service.php
2. Change the 'scope' of the next line:

   protected $scopes = array(self::SCOPE_USERINFO_PROFILE);
3. For this other:

   protected $scopes = array(self::SCOPE_USERINFO_EMAIL);
4. And finally display the mail attribute.

   $this->attributes['email'] = $info['email'];